# Is it safe to have a static instance of a mutable class?

Tags: java

I looked into the javadoc of [`FacesMessage`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/apidocs/jakarta/faces/application/facesmessage). It has setters, so I think it's not thread safe, like `SimpleDateFormat`.

Is it safe to have it as a static variable in a class?

Comment: No.  Or more accurately, it is not automatically safe.  (It depends on what your code does with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not thread-safe, although that has nothing to do with it being a static member of a class; non-static members can be shared across multiple threads as well.

```
public class Example implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example sharedInstance = new Example();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Thread(sharedInstance, "Worker " + (i + 1)).start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            System.out.println(count++);
        }
    }

    private int count;

}
```

In this example, declaring `private static int count` does not change the semantics of the program, although different outcomes may still be possible due to JVM optimizations.

So, ultimately, you will have to identify how many threads might access the instance of `FacesMessage` and what each thread might do with it at any given time. If any of those constellations involves a modification, you will have to add some form of synchronization.